# Fullscreen API without mouseclick or keydown event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, android-fullscreen

For a friend I'm creating a narrowcasting (well, not really, just to one screen) page which reads content from his webshop and shows a slideshow with highlighted items, together with his logo and the time.

To run this I'm using an Android 4.1 device with a screen, I've installed Chrome onto the device which works properly. Everything is going pretty good so far, there's just one thing that annoys me. As we speak I'm using the Fullscreen API to go fullscreen as soon as the user presses the enter key. But due to changing content I want to do a refresh once in a while to fetch new content.

Here's where the problem lies: once the page refreshes it leaves fullscreen mode. I have been looking for settings in Chrome Android to allow fullscreen mode without a mouseclick or keydown event but haven't succeeded so far. Is there any way I can get the result I want (going fullscreen without a click of keydown)?

The reason I'm using Chrome Android is because this browser gave the best HTML5 support (for future use) and the best resolution (1280x720). But it's lacking a fullscreen mode I can use from within the browser. I tried Firefox for Android with a fullscreen plugin, that worked perfectly (not leaving fullscreen when refreshing), but Firefox only gave me a 960x520 viewport which is pretty small.

There's just one thing that comes up in my mind for now, which is doing an AJAX request to fetch the new content and replace the pages HTML with the fetched HTML (or perhaps just the 'slides' container).

Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: Do you need to refresh the page? Ajax http requests could be a better solution....  Also what kind of server are you using? Php, node.js, and so on

Comment: An ajax request was one of my suggestions in the last paragraph aswel, but I have no idea how this would influence the performance of the script (can the cache become full for example, causing the js to crash?). Right now it's all PHP/jQuery/HTML5 based what I have. Node.js is an option (or needed?) since I'm planning on being able to overrule the screen in realtime from an application.

Comment: In all honesty your question is still a little vague, i suggest posting the code you have so far.

Comment: In what wat is the question vague? No source code is needed whatsoever to answer this question. Android 4.1 device with Chrome installed. I got the Fullscreen API working to go fullscreen after pressing the return key. But a page refresh breaks the fullscreen mode.

Comment: use a 100% iframe to show the content

Comment: that's a pretty good sugestion.. thanks! :)

Comment: Not exactly sure why the question gets downvoted by the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the same thing as refreshing the page automatically.  I'm not sure if it'll prevent you from exiting fullscreen because I don't have a working copy to mess around with.

```
$.ajax() //Get the current page
  .done(function(msg) {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = msg;
  });
```

I don't recommend doing somthing like this, however.  Your best bet is to abstract the part of the page that needs to be updated to it's own page, ie:

```
$.ajax("http://example.com/get_next_element")
   .done(function(msg) {
     $("selector_for_fullscreen_element").html(msg);
 });
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking aswel. If there is no option to use a regular refresh this is the only way left with (hopefully) no refresh.

Comment: without special ready() handling, this pattern tends to overload scripts; for example, a slideshow would advance two images when clicking next. it also can accumulate JS that was designed for one page or to be init() onload()

Comment: @dandavis - That's why I recommend the second strategy over the 1st.  Don't want to be overwriting any existing javascript, could be risky.  So long as the fullscreen element doesn't contain any javascript, the second strategy should work.  Aside from that, I have no context to provide anything that's more useful.

Comment: 2nd seems best for me, it's all based on the inner content of a div that needs to be updated. So mainly the body of the page. JS/CSS is all outside the container. using the 2nd example will not cause any cache issues if I reload the container like 1000 times?

Comment: IIRC, ajax does not cache data.